# Deleting everything between [ ] in each line

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++. I have a text file of 500 individual lines and they consist of:

```
12 asdfdfsdfz adf [SGH]
1 sDasd fsdfsdf [SGV]
```

and so on 500 times.

I wish to remove everything in between the brackets and the brackets themselves. How can I do that?

Comment: Using what language, platform, and toolkit? What "lines"? Is this a text file? An MS Word document? HTML? Why is this tagged with "capslock"?

Comment: Use Regular Expression to match and delete them, and now you have two problems.

Comment: Im trying to use Notepad ++ I know you can use regular expression but when using [.*?.*?] it wont find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Unix tool called `sed` and match them with RegEx, <s>and now you have two problems</s>.

```
sed 's/\[[A-Z]*\]//g' your.file > output.txt
```

Do note that this will delete them only if there's nothing but UPPERCASE letters between the brackets, i.e. it will not delete something like `[abcd]`

Strictly speaking, the above command will only delete

- An opening bracket `[`, followed by
- Zero or more uppercase letters, and followed by
- A closing bracket `]`.